# Update Ember Handlebar template when if/else condition changed

Tags: ember.js

I'm using a little "helper" function in my app to get the current user/login status:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  isAuthenticated: function() {
    return Docket.AuthManager.isAuthenticated()
  }.property('Docket.AuthManager.apiKey'),

  currentUser: function() {
    return Docket.AuthManager.get('apiKey.user')
  }.property('Docket.AuthManager.apiKey')

});
```

Now this is how my application.hbs looks:

```
{{#if isAuthenticated}}
    foo
{{else}}
    bar
{{/if}}
```

But even if `isAuthenticated` return another value, the template doesn't get it. Only solution: refreshing the page. How can I achieve that without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Shouldn't `isAuthenticated` be a computed `.property()` on the controller?

Comment: Ooops, sorry, wrong code snippet. I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Docket.AuthManager.apiKey` isn't an ember property, (which I'm pretty sure it isn't) ember won't know when it's changed causing the computed property to re-trigger and check again.  Ember is only aware of properties that are get/set using its getter and setters.

Comment: You're right, I can't see the forest for the trees. Actually the property is `Docket.Settings.apiKey` and not `Docket.AuthManager.apiKey`. Thanks for the hint!